# Peach on a dyadic function

Tags: kdb

I have two lists (with atoms of different types) and would like to apply a custom dyadic function in parallel, i.e. first element of the list `a` with first element of the list `b` etc.. The non-parallel way is to use the iterator `'`, which works just fine, but what is the parallel alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid having to flip your data, which can be expensive, by composing the peach with each both

```
q) f:{x+y}
q) l1: 1 2 3
q) l2: 4 5 6
q) (f':)'[l1;l2]
5 7 9
q)\t:100000 (f':)'[l1;l2]
97
q)\t:100000 (f .) peach flip(l1;l2)
141
```

Without the peach this would just be a simple `f'[l1;l2]`

Answer (score 3):

You can create item pairs using `flip` and then use `peach` on this list to run them in parallel.

```
q) f:{x+y}
q) l1: 1 2 3
q) l2: 4 5 6
q) (f .) peach flip(l1;l2)
```